# OBJLoader still supported?

Tags: three.js

just starting out with three.js and I'm attempting to load some objects.

I have managed to get the Blender exporter working for some simple tests and loading JSON files seems ok so far.

I have a .obj file I wanted to use and tried to use the OBJLoader but the latest (61) version of three.js doesn't seem to have this class anymore(?) There is an ObjectLoader class, but I didn't have much luck with that. Looking at the source it looks like it uses JSON.

I tried importing the .obj into Blender and exporting with the three.js plugin, but it either dropped a lot of faces or the culling is hiding them because some are drawn in the wrong direction.

So... is loading obj files supported or should I try to use JSON? In a more general sense, what's the best, most reliable method (file format, modeling software) to create models to  use with three.js now?

Comment: Yes. See the three.js examples: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. OBJLoader.js is not included in the latest version though. I tried copying one from an example, and it had problems with the model I tried:

Comment: Sorry, just getting used to stackoverflow's instant post :) Anyway, here is the error I got:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined three.min.js:283
THREE.Mesh.updateMorphTargets three.min.js:283
THREE.Mesh three.min.js:282
(anonymous function) model.js:64
(anonymous function) objloader.js:23
(anonymous function) three.min.js:215

Comment: DOH. Okay, the OBJLoader.js (and other loaders) are included in the examples/js directory! Sorry for the confusion.

Any recommendations on best formats/software still appreciated.